# GRAV variable not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

this program isn't working, and I have tried to change whatever seemed wrong to me. I am trying to simply make a game where gravity works, and do not know if I need to change everything, or just two quote marks to two apostrophes

```
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
GRAV = 0
Q_PRESSED = False
# to make the window
window = Tk()
window.title("jumpy jump")
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='white')
c.pack()
# to create the sprite
dude_id = c.create_rectangle(0, 30, 15, 100, outline='limegreen', 
fill='limegreen')
dude_id2 = c.create_rectangle(45, 30, 60, 100, outline='limegreen', 
fill='limegreen')
dude_id3 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 60, 60, outline='limegreen', 
fill='limegreen')
def is_collided_with(dude, floor):
    return self.rect.colliderect(dude.rect)
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2
c.move(dude_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(dude_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(dude_id3, MID_X, MID_Y)
floor_id = c.create_rectangle(0, 485, 800, 500, fill='black')
while Q_PRESSED != False:
    if not dude.is_collided_with(floor):
        GRAV =+ 1
        c.move(dude_id, 0, GRAV)
        c.move(dude_id2, 0, GRAV)
        c.move(dude_id3, 0, GRAV)
    if dude.is_collided_with(floor):
    GRAV =-2
    # to move
    def move_dude(event):
        if event.keysym == 'q':
            Q_PRESSED = True
        if event.keysym == 'Left':
            c.move(dude_id, -10, GRAV)
            c.move(dude_id2, -10, GRAV)
            c.move(dude_id3, -10, GRAV)
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            c.move(dude_id, 10, GRAV)
            c.move(dude_id2, 10, GRAV)
            c.move(dude_id3, 10, GRAV)
    c.bind_all('<key>', move_dude)
```

I have had some help with a book, for the binding key stuff, but it was made for kids or beginners, as I am quite new to python. Any help will be great!

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting errors? Is it performing in ways you don't expect? If so, how do you expect it to work? People here love to help, but you've got to give us enough information to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `GRAV =+ 1` and `GRAV =-2` set your variable to the constant values 1 and -2, respectively.  You probably want `+=`, `-=` here.

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Does the program crash? Is the gravity too strong? Too weak? Something else?

Comment: The program runs, but the sprite that i nicknamed "dude" does not fall, nor ascends, nor moves left/right. Sorry for the lack of info, I am quite new to this website

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a one line fix as there are multiple problems with your code that have to do with tkinter and not necessary your gravity issue:

- What is `self.rect.colliderect()`, a PyGame artifact?
- `c.bind_all('<key>', move_dude)` should probably use `<Key>`
- `move_dude()` seems to be an inner function to avoid declaring
  `Q_PRESSED` global.
- There's no call to `mainloop()`.

My minimal rework of your code to demonstrate the movement I believe you were trying to achieve:

```
from tkinter import *

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
GRAVITY = 0

def is_collided_with(dude, floor):
    return dude in c.find_overlapping(*c.bbox(floor))

def move_dude(event):
    global GRAVITY

    if is_collided_with(dude_id, floor_id):
        GRAVITY = 0
    else:
        GRAVITY += 1

    if event.keysym == 'q':
        exit()

    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        c.move(dude_id, -10, GRAVITY)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        c.move(dude_id, 10, GRAVITY)

# to make the window
window = Tk()
window.title("jumpy jump")

c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='white')
c.pack()

# to create the sprite
dude_id = c.create_rectangle(0, 30, 15, 100, outline='green', fill='green')
c.move(dude_id, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

floor_id = c.create_rectangle(0, 485, 800, 500, fill='black')

c.bind_all('<Key>', move_dude)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: question for future refrence: does the return dude in c.find_overlapping(*c.bbox(floor)) return true/false? I might try codeacademy again, as I don't understand half of a trillionth of python, and that isn't including all the plugins (pygame, time, etc.). Thanks

Comment: return dude in c.find_overlapping(c.bbox(floor))

Comment: Yes, @Rauligio, the key operation is `in` which returns a boolean -- that boolean result is then returned as the value of the function.